# Determining Alexander Mokowich's death date (after 1920), possibly in Massachusetts?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, death-records, massachusetts

Alexander Mokowich was born in Pittsfield, Massachusetts, in 1917. He was listed in a WWI military record and in a 1920 census in Pittsfield, but not in the 1930 census. When was his death date? His parents are Ignatz Mokowich and Magdeliena Stankiewicz Mokowich.

Comment: My grandfather, Steven Mokowich, and his sister, Sonia Mokowich, were the only children my family ever heard about. It is a mystery what happened to Alexander!

Comment: He was born during WWI, so what was the military record that mentioned him? His father's military record? You can add information to your question using the [edit] button below your post. Be careful not to mention identifying information about living persons.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Can you tell us what efforts you've made to find a record already?  See [How do I ask a good question?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for our site guidelines.